# Detect subtitle from an image

Tags: ocr

I need a customized idea for detect only subtitle in an image. Maybe some steps of image processing such that to be able to extract (with tesseract for example) characters from the processed image correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you cut the bottom of the image and then apply tesseract on this ? 
In bash on linux I would put the following in a bash script and apply it to all image (with xargs for example):

```
# filenames
input="$1" 
extension=$(echo $(echo "$input"|sed 's/.*\.//g'))
nomfich=$(basename $input .$extension) 
interm="$nomfich.tiff"
# convert to tiff and crop 
convert -gravity South -crop 100%x15%+0+0 -density 300 $input $interm
# ocr 
tesseract $interm $nomfich
```